# Restrict laravel routes by nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx

my domain is : mywebsite.com

also I have laravel project

I want nginx block all of the routes except /admin

I mean if I type mywebsite.com/about I don't want it to being rendered.

I need just mywebsite.com/admin routes to be render.

this is my current nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mywebsite.com;
    root /var/www/html/mywebsite-laravel/public;

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Also I know I can do something with laravel but my app is too huge project and the cost of editin laravel is really high therefore I wanna do this with nginx.

Comment: `nginx` is a web server and your web site admin is provided by your app script (larave). Both are different things, In laravel, you can use auth middleware to prevent access from laravel route.

Comment: @sta that's really huge project, the cost of editing laravel app is too much, I wanna do it by nginx

Answer (score 0):

Disable "pretty URLs" by default, unless they are admin-related,
by having an empty `/` location for and doing "pretty URLs" only in admin:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mywebsite.com;
    root /var/www/html/mywebsite-laravel/public;

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / { }

    location = /index.php { 
        return 404;
    }

    location = /admin {
        return 301 /admin/;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```